# Get latest release using nodegit

Tags: nodegit

How can I get the code from latest release of a Github repository using nodegit?

I went through this [API guide](http://www.nodegit.org/api/repository/). I also look around in `nodegit` user guides. There are examples to get the latest commit - but not the latest release.

Note: I would like to use `nodegit` instead of `github`'s api because I would like to make my code work with an internal `git` repository at a later point in time.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing:

1. Git clone to a common location, if this is the first time I am executing. [Example from nodegit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit#cloning-a-repository-and-reading-a-file).
2. Git [fetch](http://www.nodegit.org/api/repository/#fetch) on the location, for subsequent runs.

Once the repository is cloned to local machine, we can get the latest release from there to whichever work-space directory that we need it at.